# VB.net connection string to sql database

Tags: vb.net

After using the following code no errors are shown, but my database is not updated once I have made a change using my management system application.
Any recommendations ?

```
Dim constring As String = Application.StartupPath.ToString() + "\mydatabaseName.mdf"
Public c As String = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" + constring + ";Integrated      Security=True;User Instance=True"

Sub openConnection()
    conn.ConnectionString = c
    conn.Open()
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you expect to have been updated?

Comment: Please provide a proper code with the query. Just opening the connection will do nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
Dim constring As String = Application.StartupPath.ToString() + "\mydatabaseName.mdf"
Public c As String = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" + constring +         ";Integrated      Security=True;User Instance=True"

Dim conn As New SqlConnection(c)
    Dim comm As New SqlCommand
    Dim strQuery As New String = "SQL Update Query"

 Try
        comm.CommandText = strQuery
        comm.Connection = conn

        conn.Open()
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```

Change your connection string to:

```
"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" + constring + ";Initial     Catalog=mydatabaseName;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
```

Using InitialCatalog helps when there are more than one databases.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My problem is that my database is not getting changed even if i add/delete/update a record.
Should i copy my database file into my application folder ?

Comment: @Ray: You should really add more informations on how you add/delete/update a record. Otherwise nobody can help you.

Comment: @Ray: You can edit your question. Add some more code with queries.

Comment: Change your connection string to:  "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" + constring + ";Initial Catalog=mydatabaseName;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"

Comment: ok let me give you the scenario.
i made a management system which includes a sql database. works fine on my PC.
when i copy it to another PC, it doest work. bcz the connection string wasnt dynamic.
then i changed is using the above code.

Comment: now its working on the other PC. but when u make a change such as delete/insert the database wont get updated.

Comment: @Ray let us know what was the issue and mark as answered if it helped.

Comment: Dim constring As String = Application.StartupPath.ToString() + "\mydatabaseName.mdf"
Public c As String = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" + constring +         ";Integrated      Security=True;User Instance=True"

works fine when u want a dynamic connection string.